# Linux Mint Monitor Configuration

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, multi-monitor

I run dual monitors on my machine with Linux Mint; however, one screen is shared with another computer. When I switch to that computer, it disconnects from Linux and resets the monitor configuration. Then, when I switch back to Linux again, it does not remember my monitor configuration, but rather treats it as a new monitor.

Is there a way to make it remember the configuration, mainly where the screen is in relation the the other, each time I reconnect it?